# Data binding to an enum on a command in Grails

Tags: data-binding, grails, groovy

I have a class:

```
class User {
    Set<Foo> foos = []
}
```

where `Foo` is an enum:

```
class Foo { A, B, C, D}
```

I have a controller action with a parameter of type `User`

```
def someAction = {User user ->
    // impl omitted   
}
```

I've created a multi-select in a GSP

```
<g:select name="foos" multiple="true" from="${Foo.values()}"/>
```

But when I submit the form the selected values do not get bound to the `foos` property of the `User` command object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Curious - does it bind correctly if you change your User to have a single `Foo` (instead of a `Set`), and then select a single value?

Comment: @Rob - yes, that works fine. I think the Set of enums would work if I added indices to each of the options in the select, but I can't think of any painless way of doing that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grails bind collection enum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216297/grails-bind-collection-enum)

Comment: Your code works fine on Grails 1.2.1. I need to add the type in `Set` from `Set foos` to `Set<Foo> foos`

Answer (score 2):

http://www.grails.org/TipsAndTricks

Enum usage

If you want to use a Enum with a "value" String attribute (a pretty common idiom) in a  element, try this:

```
enum Rating {
    G("G"),PG("PG"),PG13("PG-13"),R("R"),NC17("NC-17"),NR("Not Rated")

    final String value

    Rating(String value) { this.value = value }

    String toString() { value }

    String getKey() { name() } 
}
```

Then add optionKey="key" to your  tag. Credit: Gregg Bolinger

Comment: I don't think this is causing the issue for Don.

Comment: In my case I don't want to explicity specify a value, I want to use the enum name as the value. Perhaps adding `String toString() {name()}` would fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really going to be an answer, per se. But I can't post the details of this in a comment.  I just created the following:

```
enum State {
  OK,KS,FL,MA
}

class User {
  Set<State> states = []

  static constraints = {
  }
}

<g:form controller="home" action="save">
    <g:select name="states" multiple="true" from="${com.orm.fun.State.values()}"/>
    <g:submitButton name="save" value="Save"/>
</g:form>

// controller action
def save = { User user ->
    // I didn't do anything here except
    // set a breakpoint for debugging
}
```

And this is what I get:

[image: Debugging in IDEA]

So I'm not entirely sure what is different between yours and mine, except the name of the enum.  Can you see anything?

Comment: did you write the GSP code to generate the multi-select or did you scaffold the UI? In my case I scaffolded the UI and controller, but the "create user" form didn't have a field for the enum

Comment: I wrote it.  All it has is the SELECT and a submit button. Edited and added it for completeness.